# Will https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth API call be valid after OAuth2 migration?

Tags: facebook, oauth, facebook-authentication, facebook-oauth

I am desperately looking for an answer to the following question that was also asked on the Forums by bromo http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=106817 .

What is the difference between what we are currently using

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=XXXXXXXX&redirect_uri=YYYYYYY
```

and what now appears in the documentation

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=XXXXXXXX&redirect_uri=YYYYYYY
```

I cannot find any reference in Facebook docs about "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth" being still valid or if it will be deprecated with Oauth2 migration.

Thanks
Dave

Comment: it's www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth in the docs currently